# Check whether the network is up on a computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I created the [`ipload`](https://github.com/m2osw/iplock) tool to ease my firewall setup. Especially, I have had a lot of problems keeping my rules *straight* (i.e. in the correct order and properly updated when managing over 3 computers).

The Ubuntu package includes an [`ipload.service`](https://github.com/m2osw/iplock/blob/main/conf/ipload.service) file which (abbreviated) looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=IP Load -- load the firewall after boot
Wants=network-pre.target systemd-modules-load.service local-fs.target
Before=network-pre.target
After=systemd-modules-load.service local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ipload --load

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So clearly, I am asking the system to start `ipload` before the network is setup (`Before=network-pre.target`). However, I would like to verify that this is indeed the case and emit a warning if I detect that the network was already up and running when I run `ipload` after a reboot.

What is the best way to check what the network status is on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to check what the network status is on Linux

**ip a** and identify the `UP` and `DOWN`

for example:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group 
2: em1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN   
3: em3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP
4: em2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN 
5: em4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP 
6: enp0s20f0u12: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
7: ib0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 4092 qdisc mq state DOWN 

# this is stripped syntax to facilitate posting here,
# the MAC address along with an ip address will also be
# displayed...  the ip address only if relevant
```

how to incorporate into your systemd service thing, idk

Comment: Excellent. That works. I already have code that replicates the **ip address** command [here](https://github.com/m2osw/libaddr/blob/main/libaddr/iface.cpp#L207).